# framing the showdown

Tags: word-meaning

I have a question about the usage of verb "frame" [here](http://www.mercurynews.com/giants/ci_26515922/giants-complete-three-game-sweep-diamondbacks):

> But that doesn't mean the fiery right-hander will be idle after setting the tone with 5-2/3 innings of stingy pitching in a 6-2 Giants victory over the Arizona Diamondbacks on Thursday, ***framing*** the upcoming National League West showdown in a most proper way.

According to dictionaries, the two senses that remotely fit the current example are 1) frame a plan (develop) or 2) frame a comment/question/answer (express it in some way).
But neither definition seems to fit the current example.  Could there be an error in the example?

Comment: "Could there be an error in the example?"  This probably shouldn't be your first guess.  Although you've asked something similar in dozens of questions, I can't recall any times you've actually *found* an error.

Answer (score 1):

Using Collins [definition](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/frame) sense 1:

> 1) to shape, fashion, or form, usually according to a pattern; design   ⇒ "to frame a constitution"

in the sense that "framing" the constitution is defining what will be contained in it.

So in your example, it is saying that the "fiery right-hander" will be a defining factor (will have a definite impact on, will shape) the events during the National League West showdown.

Answer (score 1):

*Frame* is used here in a sense that marries the general sense ‘contrive, design’ with a figurative use of the narrower sense ‘enclose in a frame’.

The Dodgers and the Giants were already bitter enemies in the 19th century, when these were the two New York teams: the Giants played in Harlem and the Dodgers across the East River in Brooklyn. Their rivalry continued when they moved to California in 1957 and the Los Angeles Dodgers and San Francisco Giants came to represent the competing economics, politics and cultures of Northern and Southern California.

The competition has been particularly intense this year, when the championship of the West division of the National League has been for the entire season a contest between these two teams. Jake Peavy's victory on Thursday night completed a three-game sweep of the lowly Diamondbacks and brought the Giants to just two games behind the Dodgers.

That makes the last two and a half weeks of the season, and in particular this weekend’s confrontation between the Giants and the Dodgers, unusually dramatic. In light of the historic rivalry the sportswriter regards it as exceptionally ‘proper’ that so much should depend on the weekend games, and he sees Peavy's performance as an event which ‘frames’ the upcoming series, as if Peavy were a playwright who ‘contrived’ the situation and put a ‘frame’ of exceptional interest around it.